# How to set custom domain in laravel

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, web, server

I make project laravel in local 127.0.0.1:8000/create but when I deploy it must 127.0.0.1:8000/project1/create

how to set, root domain to 127.0.0.1:8000/project1/

web server using apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line below the `RewriteEngine On` in `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteBase /project1
```